# EF + Code First + MemberShip

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, poco, code-first

What I'm trying to:

Get User By Id => Use the Id to get the cases the user have assigned => Return the cases.

My question is:

I know that I need to reference the MemberShip User table to the Cases table, but should I define the membership User table where I get the User as a POCO like my other tabels in my project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only ID field,then pass your class only ID.If you need more fields then you can make a custom class that holds information about User.

Also know that all the information of **User** class is retrieved from Database.There is also another way if you persist on using database by extending membership procedures.

Best Regards
Myra

Comment: So instead of passing all the fields in my User table to my class I just pass the Id and nothing else?

Comment: If you think that those field are unnecessary fields for other project,you should avoid using them.

Comment: I tried doing like you said, however I get an error: "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

 System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'aspnet_Users' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
 System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: The EntitySet aspnet_Users is based on type aspnet_Users that has no keys defined."